# Expression for density of sum of two jointly distributed random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

I read on [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s116/node114.html) that given two jointly distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$, the density of their sum (let $Z=X+Y$) can expressed as

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx \,.$$

I am trying to figure out where this formula comes from. If
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)dx \,,
$$ then I see how the original equation represents the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$, which results in the density of $Z$. However, I am not sure if the expressions above are actually equal. Could someone please help me understand how this formula is derived?

Comment: The double integral that you've written is the CDF of $Z$, not the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double integral that you've written is the CDF of $Z$, not the PDF.
Indeed, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\frac{d}{dz} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x, z-x) \, dx$$
(assuming you can push the derivative past the first integral).

Comment: Why does $f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$ represent the CDF of Z?

Comment: @goatboy3million Sketch the region that the double integral covers, and you will note it contains all points $(x,y)$ such that $x + y \le z$.